# NSFetchedResultsController throws exception

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am using NSFetchedResultsController to manage my data from Core Data, but I keep getting this exception:

```
012-05-10 21:54:32.142 test[939:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'event''
```

Here are my codes

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

what's the problem? thx

below are what I have in the data model and data class

[image]

[image]

May be there's some problem with my insert data code, so I post that as well

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];


    NSString *name = _nameField.text;
    NSString *amount = _amountField.text;

    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:amount forKey:@"amount"];
    [newManagedObject setValue:category forKey:@"category"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.delegate addContentViewControllerDidSave:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not added the entity event in managed object context model. and if you have added then you have to delete it for the first time. mean after you change in datamodel, they are not loaded into memory first time. you have to delte the app

Comment: But I have already added entity event in the data model, so that's the curious part

Comment: when u change any thing in data model you have to delte app cz ios don't merge changes in datamodel

Comment: But I have done that several times, I think the problem is not here, thx anyway bro

Comment: y don't u try deleting the app and runing it again frm xcode?

Comment: is ur entity with same name.i.e event or with caps E

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because you have changed Data Model but you have not changed `NSManagedObject` class. Here it should be **Event.h** for that entity which you changed.

Comment: as the images I have just added, there's no problem with that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Entity is named "event" rather than "Event".  Entities are supposed to start with an upper case letter, while attribute names are supposed to start out lowercase.  The standard Entity that is created is named "Event", not "event".

EDIT
According to your screenshots, the Entity is named "Event", not "event".  Also, your Entity NSManagedObject subclass should be named "Event" and not "Item".  Select the Entity and then on the main menu, click Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass.  This will create it properly.

After you get done fixing all this, make sure to Reset the simulator or delete the app from the simulator before trying to run it again.

Comment: I have check that and it's ok

Comment: No it's not.  The Entity (according to your screenshot is named "Event" not "event".

Comment: sorry mate, that's coz I changed it to try another way,I've always keep these two the same

Comment: Make the name "Event", regenerate your NSManagedObject subclass and change your FRC to NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

Comment: I tried all these but the program returned another error:The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store

Comment: Reset the simulator or delete the app from the device/simulator.  This is caused my changing the Core Data model and not using the migration tool.

Comment: Do it again. That fixes the incompatible model error every time.

Comment: well I cleaned and deleted the app in simulator and cleaned again,didn't work,maybe ti's sonething else this time

Comment: If you are running it the sim, reset it. Don't just delete the app. If something else changed (bundle id), you may have multiple instances of the app.